# Symfony 6 - Conditionally load Entities

Tags: symfony, orm

Is there a way to get Symfony to load entities only if a certain database field (or multiple) are filled?
I know I can use querybuilder to do the selection afterwards, but the database records where the fields are not filled, I will never use, so I'd rather not load them at all.

Something like:

```
#[ORM\Entity]
#[ORM\Table(name: 'department')]
#[ORM\Condition(notnull: 'fieldA', notnull: 'fieldB')]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller or type form, instead of sending your entire entity for your form, in this case you must send fields one by one.
In your front display, you put the condition that it is displayed only if field exists and is not null

More here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms

Comment: I'm sory. I meant database field, not form field.